# Have an object method return an instance of itself to the calling object

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I am trying to have a constructor in `Object X` return the `Load` method of `Object X Base Class` and then assign the data returned from the `Load` method to `Object X` and I cannot figure out how to do this. This is what I have that I thought would work:

```
public class ObjectX : BaseClass {
    public int testProperty {get; set;}

    public ObjectX(Guid id) {
        base.Load(id);
    }
}

public class BaseClass {
    public Load(Guid id) {
        var dbData = // Loads ObjectX from db
        return dbData;
    }
}
```

When I run this code the data loads perfectly, but will not assign anything to `Object X`. dbData loads the `testProperty` correctly, but when it is passed to `ObjectX` all the data disappears. I feel like I am missing something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible. A constructor cannot overwrite itself.

Consider this:

What type is dbData?

If it's not of type ObjectX, you cannot assign it to an instance of ObjectX.

If it is of type ObjectX, you'll need to construct it somewhere and then you'll have an infinite loop.

What you can do is load data from a database and then manually copy the data into your properties.

Comment: I was trying to avoid that, but oh well. Thanks for your quick answer.